# Examples of functions in a Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis

Please give me an example of two functions $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\lim\limits_{c\to +0} \int\limits_{\{x\in [0,1]:\,\, 0<|f(x)-g(x)|<c\}} |f(x)g(x)|\,dx=+\infty.
$$
Thank you very much in advance!

P.S. Thank you very much for your answer. I have modified my question since it was incorrect. Now it seems to be correct.

Comment: Are you sure this is even possible? It seems to me that this is an increasing function of $c$. Because as $c$ grows larger, the domain increases, and the integrand is always nonnegative.

Comment: Unless the intended question is something different, it looks like @Ray has answered it, and perhaps it should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Take $f(x)=g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$. Then the domain is always the same and the integral is always $+\infty$.

Actually the (new) question is weird : as $c$ decreases to zero, the value of the integral also decreases, so the only way for the limit to be infinite is for it to be infinite for all $c$. Without any additional requirement, this is achieved whenever $f=g$ and $f^2$ is not integrable though.

Comment: Thank you! And what about an example with $f\neq g$?

Comment: if you want an example where $f \neq g$, just take $g = f + \chi$ where $\chi$ is a function which is 0 on say $[0,1/2]$ and bounded (for example, equal to one on $[1/2,1]$). Then if you have chosen $f$ such that $f^2$ is not integrable but $f$ is (as in my example) then $f^2 - fg = f \chi$ is integrable so the example still works

Comment: Thank you very much! Now my problem is solved.

Comment: (then please consider validating my answer ;)